# Can I use one function for changing different states in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tsx

Can I pass the state and only use 1 function instead of calling a function for every state property?

Component state:

```
this.state =
{
  context: this.props.context,
  dataProvider: this.props.dataProvider,
  projectInformationDetails: {
    programName: "",
    projectName: "",
    projectStatus: "",
    projectStatusOptions: [],
    appStatus: "",
    appStatusOptions: [],
    governanceStatus: "",
    governanceStatusOptions: []
  },
};
```

Function for changing state when input changes:

```
private async setProgramName(e) {
    await this.setState(prevState => ({
        projectInformationDetails: {
            ...prevState.projectInformationDetails,
            programName: e.target.value,
        }
    }));

    this.props.updateProjectItem(this.state.projectInformationDetails);
}

private async setProjectName(e) {
   await this.setState(prevState => ({
      projectInformationDetails: {
         ...prevState.projectInformationDetails,
         projectName: e.target.value,
      }
   }));

   this.props.updateProjectItem(this.state.projectInformationDetails);
}
...
```

Text Component in render:

```
<TextField
    label={strings.ProgramNameLabel}
    defaultValue={this.state.projectInformationDetails.programName}
    onChange={this.setProgramName}
/>
<TextField
     label={strings.ProjectNameLabel}
     defaultValue={this.state.projectInformationDetails.projectName}
     onChange={this.setProjectName}
/>
...
```

So instead of using almost the same function for every state, I just want to use one single function:

> func(state, value)

Maybe the code will be cleaner if I can access the property of projectInformationDetails without cloning everything back.

For example:

```
this.setState( {projectInformationDetails.programName: value});
```

Comment: You actually using the **Same** function, its not clear what you are asking, if its the same function just map it. Also, why you `await` for `this.setState`? its not a promise

Comment: I strongly suggest checking out react hooks which is the preferred way, and changes completely how state is handled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is all input fields, you could add a `name` key to the input tag. It would look something like `<input type="text" name="programName" value={programName} />`
The name value would then correspond to key that you're trying to change in the state.

With this you should be able to create a generic function to set the state value.

```
const onInputChange = (e) => this.setState({
  ...this.state,
  projectInformationDetails: {
    ...this.state.projectInformationDetails,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
  },
});
```

And use this function on the input field's `onChange`.

I haven't used classes with React in a while, so there is probably some modification that needs to be done.

**Edit:**

You could incorporate part of @David Barker's answer by adding the value in the `onChange` function and using functions as first class citizens, by returning another function.

```
const onChange = (property) => (e) => this.setState({
  ...this.state,
  projectInformationDetails: {
    ...this.state.projectInformationDetails,
    [property]: e.target.value,
  },
});

...

<TextField
    label={strings.ProjectNameLabel}
    defaultValue={this.state.projectInformationDetails.projectName}
    onChange={onChange('programName')}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks this works for me! I will also try a method without using the name attr.

Comment: @tmach I've edited my response to an example that might work the way you wanted it to! Probably along the lines you thought yourself.

Comment: Thanks and yes indeed I combined the 2 answers of you.

Answer (score 1):

You could compose each event handler from a single method, I'm not sure if there would be render overheads by doing this as React wouldn't be able to keep track of the event handlers, if it does you could always assign the result to variables in `componentDidMount`.

```
private setComponentState(key) {
    const self = this;
    return (e) => {
        self.setState(prevState => ({
            projectInformationDetails: {
                ...prevState.projectInformationDetails,
                [key]: e.target.value,
            }
        }))
    };
}
```

Then call this function each time you want to use it with the key.

```
<TextField
    label={strings.ProgramNameLabel}
    defaultValue={this.state.projectInformationDetails.programName}
    onChange={this.setComponentState('programName')}
/>

<TextField
    label={strings.ProjectNameLabel}
    defaultValue={this.state.projectInformationDetails.projectName}
    onChange={this.setComponentState('projectName')}
/>
```

Comment: Hey David, Thanks for your help. Your code can work but I need to call another function at the end. Now there is a return so, it doesn't reach that line.

Comment: Apply the function to variable then, call your function, then return the event handling function.

Comment: Thanks, I combined the 2 answers.